# How to sort a Data delegate array

Tags: acumatica

I am populating data using 2 views inside a data delegate. I have to calculate running balance by sorting the based on transaction date. How do i sort the data and populate the running balance.

The delegate code is given below.

```
[PXVirtualDAC]
    public PXSelectOrderBy<FundBalanceData, OrderBy<Asc<FundBalanceData.tranDate>>> fbdata;
    protected virtual IEnumerable FBData()
    {
        List<FundBalanceData> importlist = new List<FundBalanceData>();

        PXSelectBase<ARPayment> cmd = new PXSelectJoin<ARPayment, InnerJoin<GLTran, On<ARPayment.batchNbr, Equal<GLTran.batchNbr>>,
                                                       InnerJoin<PMProject, On<GLTran.projectID, Equal<PMProject.contractID>>>>,
                                                       Where<GLTran.projectID, Equal<Current<PMProject.contractID>>,
                                                       And<ARPayment.docType, Equal<ARPaymentType.prepayment>>>>(Base);
        foreach(PXResult<ARPayment,GLTran,PMProject> line in cmd.Select())
        {
            FundBalanceData data = new FundBalanceData();
            ARPayment arp = line;
            PMProject pmp = line;
            GLTran glt = line;
            data.BAccountID = arp.CustomerID;
            data.CreditAmount = glt.CreditAmt;
            data.DebitAmount = glt.DebitAmt;
            data.RefNbr = arp.RefNbr;
            data.DocType = arp.DocType;
            data.Desc = arp.DocDesc;
            data.TranDate = arp.DocDate;
            importlist.Add(data);
        }


        PXSelectBase<APAdjust> cmd2 = new PXSelectJoin<APAdjust, LeftJoin<GLTran, On<APAdjust.adjBatchNbr, Equal<GLTran.batchNbr>, And<APAdjust.adjdAPAcct, Equal<GLTran.accountID>>>,
                                                     InnerJoin<APPayment, On<APAdjust.adjgRefNbr, Equal<APPayment.refNbr>, And<APAdjust.adjgDocType, Equal<APPayment.docType>>>,
                                                     InnerJoin<APTran,On<APTran.refNbr,Equal<APAdjust.adjdRefNbr>,And<APTran.tranType,Equal<APAdjust.adjdDocType>>>>>>,
                                                     //InnerJoin<GLTran, On<APTran.projectID, Equal<GLTran.projectID>>>>>,
                                                     Where<APAdjust.adjgDocType, Equal<APPaymentType.prepayment>, And<APTran.projectID, Equal<Current<PMProject.contractID>>, And<GLTran.accountID, NotEqual<APPayment.aPAccountID>>>>>(Base);

        foreach (PXResult<APAdjust,GLTran,APPayment,APTran> line in cmd2.Select())
        {
            FundBalanceData data = new FundBalanceData();
            APPayment arp = line;
            GLTran glt = line;
            APAdjust apd = line;
            data.BAccountID = arp.VendorID;
            data.CreditAmount = glt.CreditAmt;
            data.DebitAmount = glt.DebitAmt;
            data.RefNbr = arp.RefNbr;
            data.DocType = arp.DocType;
            data.Desc = arp.DocDesc;
            data.TranDate = arp.DocDate;
            importlist.Add(data);
        }
        decimal? balance = decimal.Zero;
        foreach(FundBalanceData data in importlist)
        {
            balance = balance + (data.CreditAmount - data.DebitAmount);
            data.Balance = balance;
        }
        return importlist;
    }
```

The array is not sorted by TranDate and the balance calculated is wrong

The result after implementing **Samvel Petrosov** suggestion

[image]

I was trying to sort the array on DateTime? and missed used the Value property. I have tried **Samvel Petrosov** suggestion and it worked.

[image]

Comment: A view order by will not order the displayed records by the order by (just by the keys). I believe the only way to do this is to make sure you are returning your list from the view delegate in the order you want.

Comment: I have tried to sort importlist array and it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the part about sorting of the Result set of data views from T200 Acumatica Framework Fundamentals Course:

> **A data view executes the delegate by the following rules:**
>
> - If a delegate is defined, invoke the delegate
>
>   - If the delegate returns null, execute the BQL command
>   - If the delegate returns an object, reorder the result according to the OrderBy clause of the BQL command
> - If a delegate is not defined, execute the BQL command
>
> The result set returned by the data view is always sorted by the ORDER
>   BY clause specified in the type of the data view object. If you sort
>   data records in a different way within the delegate, the result set
>   will be reordered before it is returned by the data view.

The calculation of the Balance in your code is done before the return of the result set. That is way it is not calculated as you are waiting. The sorting is taking place after you return the result set.

**UPDATE 1**

Change your `cmd` and `cmd2` to the following queries:

```
PXSelectBase<ARPayment> cmd = new PXSelectJoin<ARPayment, InnerJoin<GLTran, On<ARPayment.batchNbr, Equal<GLTran.batchNbr>>,
                                                       InnerJoin<PMProject, On<GLTran.projectID, Equal<PMProject.contractID>>>>,
                                                       Where<GLTran.projectID, Equal<Current<PMProject.contractID>>,
                                                       And<ARPayment.docType, Equal<ARPaymentType.prepayment>>>,OrderBy<Asc<ARPayment.DocDate>>>(Base);




PXSelectBase<APAdjust> cmd2 = new PXSelectJoin<APAdjust, LeftJoin<GLTran, On<APAdjust.adjBatchNbr, Equal<GLTran.batchNbr>, And<APAdjust.adjdAPAcct, Equal<GLTran.accountID>>>,
                                                     InnerJoin<APPayment, On<APAdjust.adjgRefNbr, Equal<APPayment.refNbr>, And<APAdjust.adjgDocType, Equal<APPayment.docType>>>,
                                                     InnerJoin<APTran,On<APTran.refNbr,Equal<APAdjust.adjdRefNbr>,And<APTran.tranType,Equal<APAdjust.adjdDocType>>>>>>,
                                                     //InnerJoin<GLTran, On<APTran.projectID, Equal<GLTran.projectID>>>>>,
                                                     Where<APAdjust.adjgDocType, Equal<APPaymentType.prepayment>, And<APTran.projectID, Equal<Current<PMProject.contractID>>, And<GLTran.accountID, NotEqual<APPayment.aPAccountID>>>>,OrderBy<Asc<APPayment.DocDate>>>(Base);
```

**UPDATE 2**

Try to add additional sorting by transaction date before the last loop:

```
importlist= importlist.OrderBy(x => x.TranDate.Value).ToList();
```

or if TranDate is not DateTime?

```
importlist= importlist.OrderBy(x => x.TranDate).ToList();
```

Comment: the final result in the grid is sorted by the date. I have to calculate the balance in the delegate to show proper balance on the grid. At present the calculated balance is not proper due to AR and AP are not sorted inside the data delegate I have tried array sort and it did not wok on DateTime? field.

Comment: @MuralidharanRamakrishnan I have added modified BQL queries to the answer try them please

Comment: I have tried and still having the issue. It requires the sorting after populating the data from 2 view

Comment: @MuralidharanRamakrishnan do you want to get the balance for the second line -1000 and -500 for the third one? Or it should be 14300 and 13800?

Comment: Second line should be 14300. It added the value from 1st and 4th line and updated on the second line. they are AR prepayments

Comment: @MuralidharanRamakrishnan try to add the following line before the last loop `importlist= importlist.OrderBy(x => x.TranDate.Value).ToList();` or `importlist= importlist.OrderBy(x => x.TranDate).ToList();` if `TranDate` is not `DateTime?`